# Spring Security LDAP - Using AuthenticationManagerBuilder rejects context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I've managed to successfully use LDAP to retrieve users from an ActiveDirectory.
However, to do so I had to manually instantiate the `BaseLdapPathContextSource` like this:

**Working Spring Security configuration:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldapProperties.getServer());
    contextSource.setUserDn(ldapProperties.getUserDN());
    contextSource.setPassword(ldapProperties.getPassword());
    contextSource.setBase(ldapProperties.getRootDN());
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    // @formatter:off
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .contextSource(contextSource)
        .userDnPatterns(new String[]{ ldapProperties.getUserOU() })
        .userSearchBase("")
        .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
        .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator((userData, username) -> 
            Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("CLIENT"))
        );
    // @formatter:on
}
```

If instead of this I use the methods provided by the builder, then every login attempt gets rejected.

**Not working Spring Security configuration:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .contextSource()
                .url(ldapProperties.getServer())
                .managerDn(ldapProperties.getUserDN())
                .managerPassword(ldapProperties.getPassword())
                .root(ldapProperties.getRootDN())
                .and()
        .userDnPatterns(new String[]{ ldapProperties.getUserOU() })
        .userSearchBase("")
        .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
        .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator((userData, username) -> 
            Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("CLIENT"))
        );
}
```

I've debugged the `ContextSourceBuilder`, and it is building a `DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource` too, similarly of how I am doing it.
The only difference between the manually built context and the one provided by the builder seems to be that `objectPostProcessor`s are applied to it after beign built. However, most of them just autowire beans.

**Log provided on a failed authentication (that should have succeeded):**

> 2018-09-25 15:45:25.679 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
>
> 2018-09-25 15:45:25.680 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : Processing authentication request for user: mcurrao
>
> 2018-09-25 15:45:25.689 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Attempting to bind as ou=factory
>
> 2018-09-25 15:45:25.689 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource : Removing pooling flag for user ou=[my_ou]
>
> 2018-09-25 15:45:25.694 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Failed to bind as OU=[my_ou]: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090400, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1

*Note: [my_ou] is actually being replaced as my own ou. But as I don't know how sensitive this is, better not risk it.*

*Note 2: This log is only provided by enabling Spring debug logging. No exception is thrown nor information is given on a login attempt if said debug is not enabled.*

This error codes seem to be just "Couldn't find your user" errors.

**TL;DR: LDAP authentication does not work if I use the provided `contextSource()` builder, forcing me to instantiate a context source.**